# Is there a way to detect if a click results in navigation to a new page?

Tags: javascript, dom

I need this from a firefox extension but I think it could apply to generic DOM programming as well.

When a navigation to a new page occurs, I would like to know if the navigation was caused by a click on an anchor, the execution of some javascript, or the user entering an address in the address bar.

In its simplest form also knowing that a click would lead to navigation to a new page would probably solve my problem.

Comment: onbeforeunload is called for both "click navigations" and "urlbar navigations" and I can't distinguish between the two...

Comment: Nope, you can't distinguish, it would fire on any redirect. It would be easy to cacht clicks on anchors, but there's no reliable way to catch javascript redirects.

Comment: May not be exhaustive, but you can catch a lot of referrals. Where do you want to use this info? On the server? In the browser? One key to getting this info on the browser would be using `document.referrer`.

Comment: It's for an extension recording users sessions so that's on the browser.